# How to join edges of 2 SVG lines?

Tags: svg

How to merge / join 2 SVG lines whose edges are intersecting ?

[image: SVG EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) to `stroke-linecap="square"` they will join/overlap.

```html
<svg xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="300"
stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square">
  <line x1="2" y1="2" x2="8" y2="2"  />
  <line x1="8" y1="2" x2="8" y2="8" />
</svg>
```